# AND'ing a sub-predicate to a base expression does not work, but the same sub-predicate when included as a part of building base predicate works

Tags: c#, .net

This approach of including sub predicate in the base expression works:

```
private void SomeCallerMethod()
{
    var predicate = GetBasePredicate(filterA:"123456");
}

private Expression<Func<Item, bool>> GetBasePredicate(string filterA)
{
    Expression<Func<PublicationItem, bool>> predicate = PublicationPredicateExtensions.GetRootExpression();
            
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterA)
        predicate = predicate.And(PublicationPredicateExtensions.Get_FilterA_Expression(filterA));

    return predicate;
}

public static Expression<Func<Item, bool>> Get_FilterA_Expression(string filterA)
{
    return (p => !p.Meta.Contains(filterA));
}
```

Building predicate collection by adding the sub predicate to the base predicate does not work:

```
basePredicate = GetBasePredicate();
basePredicate.And(p => !p.Meta.Contains("123456"));

private Expression<Func<Item, bool>> GetBasePredicate()
{
    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate = PublicationPredicateExtensions.GetRootExpression();
    return predicate;
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean; what happens? Try `AndAlso` instead of `And`

Answer (score 0):

When combining expression trees, you can't just use `And(p => !p.Meta.Contains("123456")` (or even `AndAlso`) - you need to resolve that second expression *in terms of the same parameters used by the first*. One way to do this is by using `Expression.Invoke` to *call* the inner lambda by passing in the parameter of the outer, however: this is not universally supported by all LINQ implementations. The more useful approach is to *rewrite* the second query completely (swapping all the `p` for whatever the original parameter expression was), and use the body directly; like:

```cs
Expression<Func<string, bool>> a = s => s.StartsWith("a");
Expression<Func<string, bool>> b = t => t.EndsWith("b");
var both = AndAlso(a, b);
Console.WriteLine(both); // s => (s.StartsWith("a") AndAlso s.EndsWith("b"))

// ...
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> x, Expression<Func<T, bool>> y)
{
    // GIGO
    if (x is null) return y;
    if (y is null) return x;
    // combine, swapping y's parameter if it doesn't match x's
    ParameterExpression xp = x.Parameters.Single(), yp = y.Parameters.Single();
    var yBody = ReferenceEquals(xp, yp) ? y.Body : new SwapVisitor(yp, xp).Visit(y.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(x.Body, yBody), x.Parameters);
}
class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        => ReferenceEquals(node, from) ? to : base.Visit(node);
}
```